# What is causing this white space in flexbox in Chrome and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: css, svg, flexbox

I am trying to create a simple directional pad and I am running into a problem when trying to use flexbox to separate the left and right buttons. The button components themselves are SVGs. Using `display: flex` introduces a white space on the top and bottom of the SVGs that I do not want. Strangely, if I make them divs, the problem does not exist. This only happens on Chrome, it works on Firefox.

Here is the problematic code: https://jsfiddle.net/j1etr0ph/

Here is the solution I'd like, but with the SVG: https://jsfiddle.net/j1etr0ph/1/

Even more strange, it seems to work below in Stack Overflow's code sandbox.

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#directional {
  width: 33.3%
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg id="directional" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
    <g id="circle">
      <path id="fill" fill="#D1D3D4" d="M15,29.5C7,29.5,0.5,23,0.5,15S7,0.5,15,0.5S29.5,7,29.5,15S23,29.5,15,29.5z"/>
      <path id="outline" fill="#414042" d="M15,1c7.7,0,14,6.3,14,14s-6.3,14-14,14S1,22.7,1,15S7.3,1,15,1 M15,0C6.7,0,0,6.7,0,15
        s6.7,15,15,15s15-6.7,15-15S23.3,0,15,0L15,0z"/>
    </g>
    <polygon id="arrow" fill="#414042" points="6.3,20 15,5 23.7,20  "/>
  </svg>
  <svg id="directional" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
    <g id="circle">
      <path id="fill" fill="#D1D3D4" d="M15,29.5C7,29.5,0.5,23,0.5,15S7,0.5,15,0.5S29.5,7,29.5,15S23,29.5,15,29.5z"/>
      <path id="outline" fill="#414042" d="M15,1c7.7,0,14,6.3,14,14s-6.3,14-14,14S1,22.7,1,15S7.3,1,15,1 M15,0C6.7,0,0,6.7,0,15
        s6.7,15,15,15s15-6.7,15-15S23.3,0,15,0L15,0z"/>
    </g>
    <polygon id="arrow" fill="#414042" points="6.3,20 15,5 23.7,20  "/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Does anyone know what is causing this and how I can get rid of it?

EDIT: So it seems to not be totally reproducible.
* On Windows, the problem does not exist in Firefox. In Chrome, it ONLY exists on my local site, not the JSFiddle or SO code.
* On Mac, I have not tested Firefox yet. In Chrome, it exists on my local site AND JSFiddle, but not SO.

EDIT: Paul's solution was correct, adding `height: 100%` to the SVGs solved the problem. Since it only seems to be happening on my local site(still curious as to why), here is the screenshot with and without the height property:

With `height: 100%`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gResy.png
Without: https://i.stack.imgur.com/whnxU.png

Comment: I see no whitespace in the jsfiddle you posted. Can you provide a screenshot of the problem? Thanks

Comment: The cause of that most likely lies somewhere else since the issue is yet to be seen.

Comment: Any specific browser ?

Comment: Chrome, sorry! I realized it doesn't happen on Firefox. I've edited the question.

Comment: Very weird. It is not happening on the JSFiddle anymore. I will attach a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `height: 100%` to your SVGs.

```
#directional {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j1etr0ph/2/

Comment: This was it! Thank you very much, this was driving me crazy. Strangely it only happens on my local site, not the JSFiddle anymore.